# p:radioButton with render rule is never rendered

Tags: jsf, primefaces, radio-button, server-side-rendering

EDIT: I adjusted the code, but the problem remains. See below

I have this `p:selectOneRadio`:

```
<p:selectOneRadio 
    value="#{bean.val}"
    id="val"
    layout="custom"
>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="A" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="B" />
    <p:ajax update="wrapper AData" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

and this `p:radioButton`:

```
<h:panelGroup id="wrapper">
    <p:radioButton for="val" itemIndex="0" rendered="#{bean.val != 'A'}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and `AData` contains other inputs. They are displayed only if the first radio is selected. But this is not important.

When I get a fresh page, both the radios are displayed. When I select ***one of them***, the ***first one disappear***.

The expected behavior by me is that the ***first radio disappear when selected***, and ***re-appear*** when the ***other*** one is ***selected***.

EDIT2: I tried to remove the `rendered`. It continued to ***not*** work! After I removed the update, it remains visible. But render does not work, so the radio ***never*** disappear.

What I'm wronging?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was I have to update an ancestor in common with ***both*** the `p:selectOneRadio` and the `p:radioButton`